# how to pass parameter using htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

currently my .htaccess file content following

```
RewriteRule list/(.*)/(.*)/ list.php?catnm=$1&tnm=$2
RewriteRule list/(.*)/(.*) list.php?catnm=$1&tnm=$2
```

but this works when i am generating url with list keyword in between

```
www.example.com/list/css/Introduction-of-CSS
```

convert into

```
www.example.com/list.php?catid=css&tid=Introduction-of-CSS
```

in my project now i am generating URL without list keyword

www.example.com/css/Introduction-of-CSS

what should i change in my .htaccess file?
thanks

Comment: What is the problem with simply removing `list/` from the beginning of rewrite rule?

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
RewriteEngine on 
Options -MultiViews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^list/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ list.php?catnm=$1&tnm=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Which excludes all existing files.
Or you can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
Options -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^list/([0-9A-Z_]+)/([0-9A-Z_]+)/?$ list.php?catnm=$1&tnm=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Which excludes all files with `-`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)(/?)$ list.php?catnm=$1&tnm=$2 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your .htaccess:

```
  Options +FollowSymlinks

  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://small.me/?$1 [L]

  RewriteRule ^profile/([a-z0-9]+)$ friend.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
```